# Submit dynamic forms in qtip from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, qtip2

I am dynamically getting a form with ajax and having it displayed in a tooltip. I can successfully get the forms as expected but it only appears to be submitting the first form.

I am doing the submission stuff in the success: function since that is where i get the dynamic forms.

```
    $('.EditGallery').each(function()
{       
    $(this).qtip({
        content:  {
            text: "Loading...",
            ajax: {
                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data, status) {   
                    this.set('content.text', data);

                    $(document).on('submit', '.EditGalleryForm', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        $.ajax({
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $('#EditGalleryResults').html('');  
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                $('#EditGalleryResults').html('FORM SUCCESSFULLY SUBMITTED!');
                            }
                        });
                    });             
                }                
            }
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 100
        },
        style: 'wiki'
    });
    //$(this).qtip('click', true);

});
```

So essentially when i click submit on a form FORM SUCCESSFULLY SUBMITTED! only shows for the first form i submit then it gets stuck in the first tool tip and doesn't work in the rest unless i refresh the page and submit again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was because i had the tag ID setting the data rather than CLASS. Apparently ID has to be a unique identifier, which i did not know.